# Can a matrix be written as $cU$ for $U$ unitary? For $c$ in $i\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, proof-verification

From an old qual exam:

*Determine whether the matrix*

$$R = \left( \begin{matrix} i & 0 & 2 \\ 2i & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & -1 -2i & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$$

*can be represented as $\lambda U$ where $U$ is unitary and $\lambda$ is a complex number. Is it possible with $\overline{\lambda} = -\lambda$?*

To my mind, all we need to do is check whether the eigenvalues all have the same moduli, and if they do, we can let $U =R/\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is any complex number with this modulus, in particular take $\lambda \in i\mathbb{R}$.

Is is really this simple?

Comment: IMHO you are on the wrong track.  Checking the definition of unitary gives an easy way to do this, easier than finding eigenvalues.

Answer (score 4):

If and only if $R = \lambda U$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ you have

$$R^*R = (\lambda U)^* (\lambda U) = \overline{\lambda} \lambda U^* U = |\lambda|^2 I,$$

where $|\lambda|^2 \in \mathbb{R}^+_0$.

**Edit** (a comment on your attempt)

Let

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & i \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Then the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda_{1,2} = \pm\sqrt{1+i}$, so they have the same absolute value $|\lambda_{1,2}| = \sqrt[4]{2}$, but

$$A^* A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1-i \\ 1+i & 2 \end{bmatrix} \ne cI,$$

whatever $c \in \mathbb{C}$ might be, so $A$ is not a complex multiple of a unitary matrix.

**Conclusion:** It is not enough to observe the eigenvalues, because a unitary matrix has another important property: it is normal. Checking the eigenvalues **and** the normality would be enough, as can be easily shown using the (complex) [Schur decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition).

Comment: Given $U$ unitary, $\{\lambda U \mid \lambda \in S^1 \subseteq \mathbb{C}\} \subseteq \mathcal{U}$, so the second question asked in the OP is really redundant, right?

Comment: @EricAuld I assume $\lambda \in S^1 \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ means $|\lambda| = 1$ and $\mathcal{U} = \{U: U^*U = UU^* = I\}$. In that case, $\{\lambda U: \lambda \in S^1\} = \mathcal{U}$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant for a fixed $U$. Certainly all $U \in \mathcal{U}$ are not complex multiples of the identity matrix, for instance.

Comment: @EricAuld In that case, yes, it is a subset.

Comment: I understand the Schur decomposition, but can you be explicit on how it shows normality and eigenvalues would be sufficient?

Comment: Let $A = UTU^*$, where $T$ is complex diagonal (i.e., $A$ is normal), with all its diagonal elements of the same modulus $c > 0$ (the condition on eigenvalues that you want). Define $B := c^{-1}A = U(c^{-1}T)U^*$ and check that it is unitary. So, $A = cB$ where $c \in \mathbb{C}$ and $B$ is unitary.